# How to detect if the element is on top of another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I want to do the drag and drop action in my case.

I want to apply droppable in one of my elements so when the dragged element drop in the droppable element, the second element will add another class.

Html

```
<div id='drag'>
   <img src='http://i60.tinypic.com/1191gxt.jpg' />
   <img src='http://i60.tinypic.com/1191gxt2.jpg' />
</div>

<div id ='drop'>
   <img src='object.jpg'/>
</div>
```

js

```
$('#drag').draggable();
$('#drop').droppable({
            drop: function(event, ui){
              $(this).addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
            }
        })
```

My codes don't seem to work. Can anyone help me what happened? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: malformed HTML won't help at all: `<img src='object'jpg'/>`

Comment: @Edgar when I drop the #drap element on top of the #drop element. The #drop element doesn't add a new class

Comment: @scrowler my bad. It's a typo

Comment: @FlyingCat your code is working: http://jsfiddle.net/Kv6wP/2/

Answer (score 0):

Checked your code and it's working: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kv6wP/2)

**Answer**: Check if your dependencies (jQuery, jQuery UI) are being loaded and the script is called after the document is loaded. Also make sure the image on drop area exists or at least dimensions of `#drop` are set.